# Different places to initialize variables in nested for loops

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested, initialization

I'm trying to rewrite the following code

```
int i1=0,i2=1;
while(i1<5)
{
   i1++;
   i2=0;
   while(++i2!=i1)
      cout << "x";
   cout <<"\n";
}
```

using two nested `for` loops.

---

I initially thought about

```
int j1,j2;
for(j1=0;j1<5;j1++)
{
  for(j2=0;++j2!=j1;)
     cout << "x"; 
  cout <<"\n"; 
}
```

But this causes a crash. Moving the `j++` inside the internal `for` loop does work instead

```
int j1,j2;
for(j1=0;j1<5;)
{
   for(j2=0,j1++;++j2!=j1;)
      cout << "x"; 
   cout <<"\n"; 
}
```

But I really don't understand how can it be wrong to put the `j1` increment inside the first `for` loop since `j1` should be a constant with respect to the internal `for` loop. So what can be the pourpose to declare it inside the internal `for`?

The only maybe reasonalble explanation I could give is that in the test-condition of the internal `for` loop, which is `++j2!=j1`, there is a `j1`, and this means that `j1` must be initialized inside the `for` loop, the same way `j2` is (even if `j1` is constant and `j2` varies). Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your first example "crashes" (it's an infinite loop) is because of your use of post-increments (j++) and pre-increments (++j).

Suppose you had this variable: `int number = 1;`. If you wrote

```
int answer = 5 + number++;
cout << answer;
```

It would output `6`, because when you use the post-increment, it uses the current value of the variable for that line of code, THEN adds one to that variable.

```
int answer = 5 + ++number;
cout << answer;
```

This would output `7`, because the pre-increment adds one to the variable, THEN uses that new value in your calculation.

---

The reason your first example becomes an infinite loop is because the first time through the loop `j1` is `0`. You then do this in your second loop: `for(j2=0;++j2!=j1;)`.

Because you are using the pre-increment in the second loop, `j2` STARTS at `1`. `1 != 0`, so it keeps looping, making `j2` `2` the second time, and so on. `j2` will never be equal to `j1`, because `j1` is `0` and `j2` just keeps adding 1 to itself every time it loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
      for(j2=0;++j2!=j1;)
      cout << "x";
```

Here you create infinity loop. j2 will never be equal to j1 for stooping the loop

In the second example you will skip the first iteration because of increased value for j1++

```
     for ( j2 = 0, j1++; ++j2 != j1;)
     cout << "x";
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
int i1=0,i2=1;
while(i1<5)
{
   i1++;
   i2=0;
   while(++i2!=i1)
      cout << i1 << "," << i2;
   cout <<"\n";
}
```

The simplest transformation to nested `for` loops I think is the following:

```
for(int i1=1; i1<=5; ++i1){
   for (int i2=1; i2!=i1;++i2){
       cout << "x";
   }
   cout << "\n";
}
```

[Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/99p1cxlfgWaFH7mS) you can see they produce the same output.